# WCF detecting which binding was called

Tags: wcf, authentication

I have a WCF web service, and it can be called through more than one endpoint.  How do I dynamically detect which endpoint was used?

For instance, my service can be called through HTTPS with a binding named "WSHttpBinding_TransportSecurity_IMyService" or through a Windows Integrated Authentication binding named "WSHttpBinding_WindowsSecurity_IMyService".  Depending on which one was called, I need to take a slightly different action to determine the identity of the client.

How can I approach this?  (If any more specific details are needed I can provide them.)

Comment: Isn't the point of WCF bindings so that you don't have to worry about how someone got to you?

Comment: I need to use impersonation.  Normally this is done with the 
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation=ImpersonationOption.Allowed)] attribute.  This attribute only activates when using a Windows Security binding--so this attribute means my code acts differently depending on which binding I use.  If Microsoft can make attributes that do this, I don't see why it's so bad if I do the same.

Comment: By the way, the client is not on a Windows machine, so I have no choice but to impersonate using a username and password.  I hope that clears up why I'm using HTTPS and sending the username/password to the service for it to impersonate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know the source binding to determine the callers identity you are doing something wrong. Your service should be protocol agnostic. Identity management can be accomplished using authentication policies.

Comment: I wish I could make it protocol agnostic, but I'm calling WCF methods from Java/Axis2.  Axis2 doesn't support Integrated Windows Authentication, so I can't use Windows Security, I have to use Transport Security.  I still need to impersonate the calling user, so I have to do that by tunneling the username/password through HTTPS and then impersonating a user.  In order to do this, I need service code that reads the username/password, and explicitly impersonates the user.  If I do this, it breaks any Windows Security bindings that point to the service method. Any alternative ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you try to obtain current user Windows identity

```
WindowsIdentity callerWindowsIdentity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
```

and if it's NULL try to use username/password version?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the original question:

You can use the To property of the IncomingMessageHeaders, which gives you an URI that has been used by the client.

```
OperationContext contect = OperationContext.Current;
MessageHeaders messageHeaders = contect.IncomingMessageHeaders;
Uri To = messageHeaders.To;
```